# Assignment as expression in Antlr grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, ll-grammar

I'm trying to extend [the grammar of the Tiny Language](http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/4-syntactic-analysis-of-tl.html) to treat assignment as expression.  Thus it would be valid to write

```
a = b = 1; // -> a = (b = 1)
a = 2 * (b = 1); // contrived but valid
a = 1 = 2; // invalid
```

Assignment differs from other operators in two aspects.  It's right associative (not a big deal), and its left-hand side is has to be a variable.  So I changed the grammar like this

```
statement: assignmentExpr | functionCall ...;

assignmentExpr: Identifier indexes? '=' expression;

expression: assignmentExpr | condExpr;
```

It doesn't work, because it contains a non-LL(*) decision.  I also tried this variant:

```
assignmentExpr: Identifier indexes? '=' (expression | condExpr);
```

but I got the same error.  I am interested in

- This specific question
- Given a grammar with a non-LL(*) decision, how to find the two paths that cause the problem
- How to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you need to "assure" the parser that inside an expression, there is something ahead that satisfies the expression. This can be done using a syntactic predicate (the `( ... )=>` parts in the `add` and `mult` rules).

A quick demo:

```java
grammar TL;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  ASSIGN;
}

parse
  :  stat* EOF -> ^(ROOT stat+)
  ;

stat
  :  expr ';' -> expr
  ;

expr
  :  add
  ;

add
  :  mult ((('+' | '-') mult)=> ('+' | '-')^ mult)*
  ;

mult
  :  atom ((('*' | '/') atom)=> ('*' | '/')^ atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  (Id -> Id) ('=' expr -> ^(ASSIGN Id expr))?
  |  Num
  |  '(' expr ')' -> expr
  ;

Comment : '//' ~('\r' | '\n')* {skip();};
Id      : 'a'..'z'+;
Num     : '0'..'9'+;
Space   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

which will parse the input:

```java
a = b = 1;       // -> a = (b = 1)
a = 2 * (b = 1); // contrived but valid
```

into the following AST:

[image]

Comment: It helped me reduce all warnings in my bigger grammar I'm writing.  Some background for this I found useful: http://dslmeinte.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/using-syntactic-predicates-in-xtext-part-1/

Comment: Good to hear that @Adam. Yeah, I read somehwere that the latest version of XText was supporting predicates: thanks for the link. I haven't looked at XText very closely, but what I _have_ seen of it looks impressive!

Comment: @AdamSchmideg, also see Vladimir Radojicic's answer, which is much cleaner (and should be the accepted answer, IMO).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change your grammar like this to achieve the same, without using syntactic predicates:

```
statement: Expr ';' | functionCall ';'...;

Expr: Identifier indexes? '=' Expr  |  condExpr ;

condExpr: .... and so on;
```

I altered Bart's example with this idea in mind:

```
grammar TL;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
}

parse
  :  stat+ EOF -> ^(ROOT stat+)
  ;

stat
  :  expr ';' 
  ;

expr
  : Id Assign expr -> ^(Assign Id expr)

  | add
  ;

add
  :  mult (('+' | '-')^ mult)*
  ;

mult
  :  atom (('*' | '/')^ atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  Id
  |  Num
  |  '('! expr ')' !
  ;

Assign  :   '=' ;
Comment : '//' ~('\r' | '\n')* {skip();};
Id      : 'a'..'z'+;
Num     : '0'..'9'+;
Space   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

And for the input:

```
a=b=4;
a = 2 * (b = 1);
```

you get following parse tree:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your opinion very much!